# How can i load data from ajax to Chosen jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select, jquery-chosen

I have use chosen at http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/ . Ok, i testing it load data from ajax . I founding anywhere, maybe no someone success with them.

```js
<script src="theme/js/jQuery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <link href="theme/chosen_v1.4.2/chosen.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="theme/chosen_v1.4.2/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
       $(document).ready(function () {
           $(".cb_bu_info").chosen({
               width: "95%",
               source: function (data) {
                   $.ajax({
                       type: "POST",
                       url: "../BUS/WebService.asmx/LIST_BU",
                       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                       dataType: "json",
                       success: function (data) {
                           $("#cb_info").html('');
                           //$.each($.parseJSON(data.d), function (idx, obj) {
                           $.each(data, function (idx, obj) {
                               $("#cb_info").append('<option value="' + obj.BU_ID + '">' + obj.BU_NAME + '</option>');
                           });  
                          //$("#cb_info").trigger("liszt:updated");
                       },
                       error: function (data) {
                           console.log(data.d);
                       }
                   });
               }
           });

           $("#cb_info").trigger("liszt:updated");
        });
    </script>
```

```html
<select id="cb_info" class="cb_bu_info"></select>
```

The data form ajax as

```
[{"BU_ID":"B01","BU_NAME":"Agro Feed","BU_DES":"Agro Feed","EDIT_DATE":"2015-05-05T00:00:00","EDIT_BY":"","FLAG":false},{"BU_ID":"B02","BU_NAME":"Agro Farm","BU_DES":"Agro Farm","EDIT_DATE":"2015-05-05T00:00:00","EDIT_BY":"","FLAG":false}]
```

Well , it's look ok , but when i run it , result not show in select option, see browser dev tool , I've not seen error. Anything is ok.What's the problem happen in here? Notes: only use Chosen Jquery

Comment: You have to first do a `var data = JSON.parse(obj);` and then `data.BU_ID`. It will work

Comment: Dear @Gagan Jaura .Are you sure ? .

Comment: Yup sure. If you can make a jsFiddle then I can show you how.

Comment: @Gagan Jaura .. Ishettyl . I try but it's not work . I'll make it jsFiddle . wait for minutes.

Comment: If the contentType is set to application/JSON then no parsing is needed so you have another problem

Comment: It should just work with what you have. Take a [look at this.](http://jsfiddle.net/by4d528c/)

Comment: Do you get that JSON response when you console.log(data) on Ajax success?

Comment: Dear all. It've still not work .Please notes chosen jquery

Comment: You have not answered my last question

Comment: Could you please answer CodeGodie answer? The key is in data.

Comment: How do you know Chosen has the "source" option? Where's the documentation for this?

Comment: Dear @CodeGodie , I'm so sory, I not see data at console.log . Please check at  https://jsfiddle.net/headshot9x9/1ru3Lg0g/1/

Comment: The fiddle doesn't work because you have not added the external Chosen library

Comment: Dear @CodeGodie, i think it's use source to bind data from ajax to chosen ^~^

Comment: But how are you sure? Where can I find this in the documentation? Or are you just assuming?

Comment: CodeGodie is right. If you comment out `$(".cb_bu_info").chosen();` then the code is working fine https://jsfiddle.net/GaganJaura/1ru3Lg0g/2/

Comment: Ohm, i updated link at http://jsfiddle.net/headshot9x9/by4d528c/1/ . please , see it .

Comment: @CodeGodie , in this link http://jsfiddle.net/LjtVa/ as chosen jquery

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After checking out the Chosen docs, there seems to not be a "source" option. What you need to do is first run your Ajax call, then fill your select options. Once the select is all filled, then run Chosen on that select element.

I would use the following JS code:

```
var url = "../BUS/WebService.asmx/LIST_BU";
$.getJSON(url, function(json){
    var $select_elem = $("#cb_info");
    $select_elem.empty();
    $.each(json, function (idx, obj) {
        $select_elem.append('<option value="' + obj.BU_ID + '">' + obj.BU_NAME + '</option>');
    });
    $select_elem.chosen({ width: "95%" });
})
```

Comment: Yes, it's right. not be "source" . I understand as you say
1: Run ajax and bind data select .2:run select as chosen

Comment: Also if you are simply obtaining JSON I would use $.getJson instead

Comment: Thank you, i'll notes and remember it.It's a answer of this question

Comment: Im glad I was able to help. Thank you and take care.

Comment: That helped me, though indirectly. In my case the dropdown was binding fine, but chosen did not seem to work as I called it after the function(that handled data using ajax). Probably chosen was not getting data. Initiating the chosen call inside the function after data was binded to dropdow did the trick.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, After some time with the help of suggestions from everybody, I have done

```
 function load_cb_info() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "../BUS/WebService.asmx/LIST_BU",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#cb_info").html('');
                    $.each($.parseJSON(data.d), function (idx, obj) {
                    //$.each(data, function (idx, obj) {
                        $("#cb_info").append('<option value="' + obj.BU_ID + '">' + obj.BU_NAME + '</option>');
                    });
                    $("#cb_info").trigger("liszt:updated");
                    $("#cb_info").chosen({ width: "95%" });
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    console.log(data.d);
                }
            });
        }
```

And , I think this is an answer and everyone else can find it .Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can try as follows it works for me

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success:function(data){
            if($.trim(data) != "no"){
                $("#PROGRAM_ID").html(data);
                $("#PROGRAM_ID").trigger("chosen:updated");
            }               
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I have changed your jsfiddle. Try this out http://jsfiddle.net/GaganJaura/by4d528c/2/

I have moved the chosen() to bottom.

```
$("#cb_info").empty();
$.each(data, function (idx, obj) {
    $("#cb_info").append('<option value="' + obj.BU_ID + '">' + obj.BU_NAME + '</option>');
}); 
  $("#cb_info").trigger("liszt:updated");

$("#cb_info").chosen();
```

Comment: Do you really need that trigger function?

Comment: Nope. Actually I just used his Fiddle and make it work. That trigger function is not needed.

Comment: Dear Gagan ,I think it should

Comment: Just doing this now I've found I needed the trigger. Note though, as per the [docs](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) I had to use `$("#cb_info").trigger("chosen:updated");`.

Answer (score 0):

> try this. it works for me. please pay attention to the bold text

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
url:'<?php echo base_url()."index.php/";?>ttemuan31a/cari_divisi',
method:'post',
params:{

        divisi:vdivisi

    },
success:function(data)
{
    $("#divisi").chosen();
        //document.getElementById('detail_divisi').innerHTML=response.responseText;
    $('#divisi').empty();

    $.each(JSON.parse(**data.responseText**), function(i, item) {
        $('#divisi').append('<option value="'+item.id+'">'+item.namadivisi+'</option>');
        $("#divisi").trigger("chosen:updated");
    });
    }
});
}
```